# How to prevent/cancel a combobox's value change in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox at the top of a form that loads editable data into fields below.  If the user has made changes, but not saved, and tries to select a different option from the combobox, I want to warn them and give them a chance to cancel or save.

I am in need of a "BeforeValueChange" event with a cancelable event argument.

Any advice on how to accomplish?

Answer (score 19):

Save the ComboBox's SelectedIndex when to box if first entered, and then restore it's value when you need to cancel the change.

```
cbx_Example.Enter += cbx_Example_Enter;
cbx_Example.SelectionChangeCommitted += cbx_Example_SelectionChangeCommitted;

...

private int prevExampleIndex = 0;
private void cbx_Example_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    prevExampleIndex = cbx_Example.SelectedIndex;
}

private void cbx_Example_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // some custom flag to determine Edit mode
    if (mode == FormModes.EDIT) 
    {
        cbx_Example.SelectedIndex = prevExampleIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution in lieu of a SelectionChanging event.  Thank you!! -- Matthew

Comment: Using the `Enter` event to save the last selection is not necessary.  Just save a `lastSelectedIndex` value as a `private` variable, before exiting the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event handler. Thereafter, subsequent entries into that event handler can use `lastSelectedIndex` to set `ComboBox.SelectedIndex` to the previous position.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the simplest fix:-

```
        bool isSelectionHandled = true;

        void CmbBx_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isSelectionHandled)
            {
                MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you wish to continue selection change?", this.Title, MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
                if (result == MessageBoxResult.No)
                {
                    ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)sender;
                    isSelectionHandled = false;
                    if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
                        combo.SelectedItem = e.RemovedItems[0];
                    return;
                }
            }
            isSelectionHandled = true;
        }
```

Comment: What is this event `SelectionChanged`? Is it from WinForm ComboBox.

Comment: @i486 Yes, it is.

Answer (score 4):

Save the current value on the `Enter` event.
Implement the `BeforeValueChange` logic in the `ValueChanged` event, before the actual `ValueChanged` logic. If the user cancels, set the stored value and don't continue in the method (`return`).

If you're going to use this system a lot, I'd suggest inheriting ComboBox and implementing your `BeforeValuechange` event there.

Answer (score 2):

The Validating event can be used for this scenario
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx

Comment: This happens after you lose focus, so will not work.  I need an event that happens "before" the user tries to change the value.

Comment: @RG - could you not just set the focus back to the combo box, or is there some processing happening when it loses focus?

Answer (score 1):

You don't get an appropriate event by default. You could cache the previous value and set it back to that if the user wants to cancel.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the Validating / Validated events?
It works well, if the event happening on LostFocus instead of Change is ok with you.

Otherwise, how about

```
public void Combobox_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!AskUserIfHeIsSureHeWantsToChangeTheValue())
    {
        // Set previous value
        return;
    }

    // perform rest of onChange code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't really prevent it, but you can change it back to the old value if certain requirements aren't met:

```
private SomeObject = selectedSomeObject=null;

private void cbxTemplates_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!(sender is ComboBox cb)) return;
  if (!(cb.SelectedItem is SomeObject tem)) return;
  if (MessageBox.Show("You sure?", "??.",
        MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) != DialogResult.OK)
    cb.SelectedItem = selectedSomeObject;
  else
  {
    selectedSomeObject = tem;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [message filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter.aspx) to intercept clicks and key presses, which would allow you to prevent the combo box's normal behaviour.  But I think you'd be better off disabling the combo box when the user makes a change, and require them to either save or revert their changes.