# Prevent selecting new listbox item if current one has invalid property

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

My settings form has listbox with objects of custom class in it. The custom class has few properties including an IP address.

All the properties have their own textboxes in the form and their values get saved in the list in textbox' textchanged event. Such as:

```
    private void textBoxIP_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        item item = (item)listBox1.SelectedItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
          item.IP = textBoxIP.Text;
        }            
        listBox1.DataSource = null;
        listBox1.DataSource = lista;
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
    }
```

Here is code for SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        item item = (item) listBox1.SelectedItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            textBoxName.Text = item.name;
            textBoxDesc.Text = item.desc;
            textBoxIP.Text = item.IP.ToString();
            textBoxPort.Text = item.port.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Now I need a way to prevent user from selecting a new index in listbox with some feedback if the IP address is invalid. I can't figure out how to do this. I do have a method for checking the validity of IP string that returns true or false.

Comment: IIRC, (Disclaimer: It's been a while since I've used WinForms) all you need to do is to set `e.Cancel = True;` and that will cause the selected index not to change.  You just need to wrap that inside an if statement that checks if the form is incomplete.

Comment: Though, it seems I may not be remembering correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556220/cancelling-listbox-selectedindexchange-event

Comment: Why are you even put the IP in the list if it is not valid?  Just disable the ListBox if the TextBox IP is not valid.

Comment: @Blam That is a really good point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why even put the IP in the ListBox if it is not valid?

Disable the ListBox when the textBoxIP.Text is not valid.