# How do I disable selection in a listbox for users but not the program? c#

Tags: c#, listbox

Is it possible to make a ListBox ReadOnly? - Technically yes. Set the "Enabled" property to False.

Selection: None break my program because it's trying to select them from the program, but if a user selects one, I don't want it to change, or highlight. I want all highlighting done by the program, is this possible?

This picture shows what I have on my Form
[image: Image of selections]

My problem is, it works perfectly fine, I just want it nicer, by only allowing the user to click on only one of the selections from the red box, while they cannot select one from the blue boxes, but the computer can.

Comment: is there a  ReadOnly attribute?

Comment: why dont you add one bool flag property to do this?

Comment: @TMcKeown No, I do not see one if there is, I see "Multi Column | RightToLeft | ScrollAlwaysVisible"

Comment: didnt understand, can you explain more?

Comment: I basically need my listboxes to be read only but there is not a property for that in the properties window.

Comment: Is there IsEnabled property in ListBox? If there is then set it to false

Comment: Yes, there is. And that is actually what I wanted, why is it named "enabled" -_- should be readonly ;) thank you

Comment: Your GUI is just wrong.  You should get rid of all of those ListBoxes in blue and when the User selects an item from the red List, just populate a read-only grid or a bunch of labels, etc with the information to be shown.  Don't give a user interaction controls if they can't interact with them.

Comment: Enabled works well but it changes the UI look to a grayed out look.

Comment: Only reason they are listboxes is for the blue highlight when selected, otherwise I would have used labels @LarsTech

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that you are using WinForms, not WPF.  So a simple way is to add a bool flag for each list control to your form.  Then on the Selection changed event prevent the change from occurring unless you've set the bool to true.  That will allow you turn on/off selected item changes.

Actually here is a link here, instead of bool just create an `int` to store the current index for each list box.  Upon the Selection changing simply set the `SelectedItemIndex` to the int variable.

[Cancelling ListBox SelectedIndexChange Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556220/cancelling-listbox-selectedindexchange-event)

Comment: Would this require me to double click each of the listboxes, add in a bool that resets it if the user clicks in there? - That's exactly what  I don't want to do, makes a mess in the code :x

Comment: Hmm, I think using the Winform Property in ListBox "Enabled" is what works exactly how I need it, thanks for the extra information though. (Comments in my main post showed me that - didn't wanna touch it cause I thought it would remove the visuals of the listbox lol)