# how to prevent an event for first time running in C#

Tags: c#

I have a Combobox that hav an event like this:

```
private void CowTypeSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("  آیا مطمئن هستید","",
            MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            NotGrazingradioButton.Checked = true;

            if (CowTypeSelect.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                CowTypeDefaults.LactatingCow(this);
                CowTypeVarlbl.Text = "گاو شیری";
            }
            else if (CowTypeSelect.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                CowTypeDefaults.DryCow(this);
                CowTypeVarlbl.Text = "گاو خشک";
            }
            else if (CowTypeSelect.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                CowTypeDefaults.ReplacementHeifer(this);
                CowTypeVarlbl.Text = "تلیسه جایگزین";
            }
            else
            {
                CowTypeDefaults.YoungCalf(this);
                CowTypeVarlbl.Text = "گوساله";
            }
        }

    }
```

but I set a default index for this combox in load form,

now the problem is that when I run the program before it even opened the messageBox shows firs, is there any way to prevent the logic if to don't run in the first time?

//-----

as you said I changed the code like this:

```
    bool FirstRun = true;
    private void CowTypeSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FirstRun == true)
        {
            FirstRun = false;
            return;
        }

        if (MessageBox.Show("آیا مطمئن هستید؟", "", 
  MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.OK)

        {
            NotGrazingradioButton.Checked = true;

        if (CowTypeSelect.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            CowTypeDefaults.LactatingCow(this);
            CowTypeVarlbl.Text = "گاو شیری";
        }

        else if (CowTypeSelect.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            CowTypeDefaults.DryCow(this);
            CowTypeVarlbl.Text = "گاو خشک";
        }
        else if (CowTypeSelect.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            CowTypeDefaults.ReplacementHeifer(this);
            CowTypeVarlbl.Text = "تلیسه جایگزین";
        }
        else
        {
            CowTypeDefaults.YoungCalf(this);
            CowTypeVarlbl.Text = "گوساله";
        }

        }
```

but now the problem is that these code doesn't run for the first time and I need them to run:

```
    NotGrazingradioButton.Checked = true;

    if (CowTypeSelect.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        CowTypeDefaults.LactatingCow(this);
        CowTypeVarlbl.Text = "گاو شیری";
    }
```

what should I do ?

Comment: add a boolean "firstrun" ? if first run skip the messages and set firstrun to false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you don't understands @Patrick Hofman's code.

The `firstRun` variable indicates whether the function is executed in the first time.

and the lines below means if it's executed for the first time, it changes `firstRun` to `false` and stop executing the codes after the `return;` line. (I've added some comments to make it clearer to you.)

```
// Put codes here if you want it to execute every time.
if (firstRun)
{
    // Codes here execute at the first time only.
    firstRun = false;
    return;
}
//Codes here execute except the first time.
```

**Fixed Code**

This runs the below lines at the first time

```
NotGrazingradioButton.Checked = true;

if (CowTypeSelect.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    CowTypeDefaults.LactatingCow(this);
    CowTypeVarlbl.Text = "گاو شیری";
}
```

and lines after `if (MessageBox.Show(...))` runs except the first time

Full code below:

```
bool FirstRun = true;
private void CowTypeSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FirstRun == true)
    {
        // Codes here execute at the first time only.
        NotGrazingradioButton.Checked = true;
        if (CowTypeSelect.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            CowTypeDefaults.LactatingCow(this);
            CowTypeVarlbl.Text = "گاو شیری";
        }
        FirstRun = false;
        return;
    }

    //Codes below execute except the first time.
    if (MessageBox.Show("آیا مطمئن هستید؟", "", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        NotGrazingradioButton.Checked = true;

        if (CowTypeSelect.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            CowTypeDefaults.LactatingCow(this);
            CowTypeVarlbl.Text = "گاو شیری";
        }

        else if (CowTypeSelect.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            CowTypeDefaults.DryCow(this);
            CowTypeVarlbl.Text = "گاو خشک";
        }
        else if (CowTypeSelect.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            CowTypeDefaults.ReplacementHeifer(this);
            CowTypeVarlbl.Text = "تلیسه جایگزین";
        }
        else
        {
            CowTypeDefaults.YoungCalf(this);
            CowTypeVarlbl.Text = "گوساله";
        }
    }
```

Comment: tank you so much, Now I have another question,
when the user select cancel button on show dialog the event don't run but the problem is that the combobox item stays on the new selected item (that has been canceled) and don't back to previous item, how can solve this matter ??

Comment: Make a variable saving the previous state of the `combobox`, then check if the user presses `cancel`, and decide whether to keep the new value or roll back to the old one.

Comment: This is unrelated with your current question, and my answer is already quite long here. I'll give you a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556220/cancelling-listbox-selectedindexchange-event) instead, since teaching someone to catch a fish is better than giving them fishes :)

Answer (score 3):

You either register the event handler after you loaded the combobox, or you build in a check on the first run, something like this:

```
private bool firstRun = true;
```

In your method:

```
if (firstRun)
{
    firstRun = false;
    return;
}
```