# combox box error

Tags: c#

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox Combo_Design = new ComboBox();
        Combo_Quality.Items.Add("Best");
        Combo_Quality.Items.Add("Normal");
        Combo_Quality.Items.Add("Draft");

        Combo_Quality.Text = "Best";

        MessageBox.Show(Combo_Quality.Text);

        string selectedItem = Combo_Quality.Items[Combo_Quality.SelectedIndex].ToString(); 

        Combo_Quality.Text = "Normal";

        MessageBox.Show(Combo_Quality.Text);

        string selectedItem2 = Combo_Quality.Items[Combo_Quality.SelectedIndex].ToString(); 

        Combo_Quality.Text = "Draft";

        MessageBox.Show(Combo_Quality.Text);

        string selectedItem3 = Combo_Quality.Items[Combo_Quality.SelectedIndex].ToString(); 



    }
```

This relates to combo box, i have 3 items to select but i want it to be when i choose best a message box to pops out and let me select ok and same goes to normal and draf

Comment: Why are you creating a new Combo_Design ComboBox?

Comment: Why are you using 3 comboboxes? ComboBox1,Combo_Design,Combo_Quality

Comment: i cant get u.Can u explain it clearly tat what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to **alert** the selected text, you could:

```
MessageBox.Show(Combo_Quality.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

if you want to **confirm** and allow the user to cancel his selection look into this question:
[How to prevent/cancel a combobox's value change in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314503/how-to-prevent-cancel-a-comboboxs-value-change-in-c)

Comment: adter i tried MessageBox.Show(Combo_Quality.SelectedItem.ToString());  still whichever i choose, best, normal or draft, the msgbox will still be shown as best..so if i choose normal , msgbox will still show as best..pls adv..thks

Comment: @junjie Are you sure it is the same ComboBox??? i see that the event is called `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`. howver you are referencing a combobox called `Combo_Quality`. which is it that you are selecting? try `MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());`

Comment: hi..ya..its the same combobox as i change the name to combo_Quality , still it doesnt wk..i will try to fix it..thks alot

Comment: @junjie put the `MessageBox.Show` on the first line of the function - before it adds other items and other crap.