# WPF How to cancel user's selection in combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf

There is a combobox with some items.

If user wants to select the other item, I want to show a Yes-No question box to confirm.

If the user clicks on 'No' , then change will be canceled.

I do this in "SelectionChanged" event handle, but if I cancel the change and select the old item, this event fires again and agin...

- How to avoid it?
- How to ask yes/no before changing the selection?

Comment: check out the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608128/how-to-cancel-a-combobox-selectionchanged-event)

Comment: First thing what comes in mind is to use flag to prevent event processing, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8843675/1997232). If you would use MVVM (or bingings at least), then you can run this logic in the setter of property bound to `SelectedItem`, this way it won't backfire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not care about displaying the value to change to before really accepting the change (by clicking "Yes") you could try to use the [SelectionChangeCommitted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted?view=netframework-4.7) event handler to handle these changes and display the user dialog.

Comment: This is a WPF project ,no SelectionChangedCommitted Event there

Comment: Ahh, you're right, that's only available in Forms. Have you tried (1) disconnecting the `EventHandler`, (2) setting the selection back, and (3) re-attaching the `EventHandler`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ask user after user trying to change that use this event handler  `SelectionChangeCommitted`.
You can also change the state of Combo box to initial form by simply set the index number of combobox to `-1`

```
 comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

so you can write the code above in click event handler of "No" button.

Comment: This will cancel any selection (i.e. select no item at all), not restore a previously selected item.

Comment: Store index number at local variable in the class Form @vonludi