# How to cancel a combobox's value change in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox.

If the user has made changes, but not saved, and tries to select a different option from the combobox, a messageBox warn them and give them a chance to

1 cancel (keep changes)

2 No  (discard changes)

3 Yes (save the chages)

for example:

the combobox contains on the values

Computer

Laptop

Phone

TV

Camera

The user chose the "Camera" then changed it to "Camera78778"
then the user chose another value (say "Computer" ) from the combobox

the messageBox warn them and give them a chance to

1 cancel (keep changes): the combox is "Camera78778"

2 No  (discard changes): the combox is "Computer"

3 Yes (save the chages): the combox is "Computer" but here the changes has saved.

I need the code of the cancel.

I tried comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= comboBox1._SelectedIndexChanged;
but no solution.
 and I tried comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted but no solution.

thanks advanced.

UPDATE

```
    int lastIndexcomboBox1 = -1;

    private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Myfunction(comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
    }

    private void Myfunction(int comboBox1SelectedIndex)
    {

        if(comboBox1.Tag.ToString() == "not changed")
        {

        }
        else
        {
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
            if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            {

            }
            else if (dr == DialogResult.No)
            {

            }
            else if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = lastIndexcomboBox1;
                comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Because you using `SelectionChangeCommitted` you do not need to "Remove" and then "Add" event handler of `SelectedIndexChanged` event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent/cancel a combobox's value change in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314503/how-to-prevent-cancel-a-comboboxs-value-change-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

You could keep information about currently selected index in private variable and do something like this:

```
private int _comboBoxIndex = -1;
private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Confirm your action", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);

    switch (dialogResult)
    {
        // Detach event just to avoid popping message box again
        case DialogResult.Cancel: 
            comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
            comboBox.SelectedIndex = _comboBoxIndex;
            comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
            break;
        case DialogResult.No:
            // Do something
            _comboBoxIndex = comboBox.SelectedIndex;
            break;
        case DialogResult.Yes:
            // Do something
            _comboBoxIndex = comboBox.SelectedIndex;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but i the changes to the combobox's value had gone

Comment: @mukhtarghaleb Can you post your code? I'm not sure what's bothering you. This is working fine in my test case.