# NumericUpDown ValueChanged preventDefault?

Tags: c#

I want to create a form that allows the user to set a certain amount of points in five different fields (NumericUpDown). When that amount of points reaches 0, the user can't add any more. (I still want the user to be able to remove points, though.)

Here is my code so far:

```
private void calculateValue() {
  decimal tempValue = CMB_num_Aim.Value + CMB_num_Reflexes.Value + 
  CMB_num_Positioning.Value + CMB_num_Movement.Value + CMB_num_Teamwork.Value;
  controlValue = currentValue - tempValue;
  MyBox.CMB_tb_cv.Text = controlValue.ToString();
}
```

This Method (calculateValue) is calculates how many points the user have left (controlValue).

```
private void CMB_num_Aim_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  calculateValue();
  if (controlValue < 0) {
     //Prevent Default here
     MessageBox.Show("You are out of points!");
  }
}
```

This method (CMB_num_Aim_ValueChanged) fires when the value of the NumericUpDown control has changed. I have one of these for each field, each doing the same thing.

The method fires as expected, but I can't prevent it from happening - the user can apply more points than they have. How can I prevent the user from applying more points?

(I thought about making a mouseUp method, but I don't know if the user will use the mouse or if he will type in the value using the keyboard.)

Comment: Set the minimum amount to be zero using the property

Comment: you can prevent by setting the previous value, store the previous value and set it back in valuechanged event

Comment: Krishna - I thought about doing that, but I haven't figured out a reliable way to do it, without accidentally overwriting my "oldValue" with the one that just fired.

Comment: keep the old value in the Tag property so that you don't need to maintain variables. whenever the validation is correct then update tag property

Comment: One more thing you can do is to validate the form before submit and alert user to set the value back which is easier

Comment: you can also use some thing like this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10093/Validators-for-Windows-Forms-ValidationProvider-Co

Comment: It sounds like a similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314503/how-to-prevent-cancel-a-comboboxs-value-change-in-c) about ComboBox controls. Sometimes the provided controls are a bit lacking in functionality, and extending them can be a good approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to create a point distribution system between some skills - aim, movement, teamwork etc. You can do that easily by setting `Maximum` value of `NumericUpDown` control when you enter it. Subscribe *all* skill updown controls to the same event handler:

```
private void SkillNumericUpDown_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var skill = (NumericUpDown)sender;
   var availablePoints = 42;
   var maxSkillPoints = 20; // usually you cannot assign all points to one skill
   var unassignedPoints = availablePoints - SkillPointsAssigned;
   skill.Maximum = Math.Min(maxSkillPoints, unassignedPoints  + skill.Value);

   if (unassignedPoints == 0)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("You are out of points!");
       return;
   }

   if (skill.Value == maxSkillPoints)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Skill maximized!");
       return;
   }
}

private decimal SkillPointsAssigned =>
    CMB_num_Aim.Value + 
    CMB_num_Reflexes.Value + 
    CMB_num_Positioning.Value + 
    CMB_num_Movement.Value + 
    CMB_num_Teamwork.Value;
```

Benefit - you will not be able to input illegal value neither by arrows nor manually.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if (controlValue < 0) {
```

By

```
if (controlValue <= 0) {
```